# Difference between declaring stringstream ss; and std::stringstream ss; in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++, and I have a simple question. Let's say I want to declare a `stringstream` object or any other. Is there any difference in using the fully-qualified name `std::stringstream` and just declaring the object as `stringstream`? I've seen it done both ways in code examples.

As I said, I'm pretty new to C++, so I'd love some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `stringstream ss;` implies the use of the horrible `using namespace std;` or the only slightly less horrible `using std::stringstream;` directives. Do yourself a favor and just go with `std::stringstream ss;`.

Comment: For the `stringstream` they probably have at some point a `using namespace std`. The main difference between using `std::stringstream` and `stringstream` would be in the case theres also something else called `stringstream` (not from std). In the second case, the compiler will give an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that unless you've done something abominable like `using namespace std;` the former will compile and the latter won't.

Comment: "abominable" -- Sir, you just taught me a new word today.

Comment: Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?

Comment: @RAF1940 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice  Verbatim =)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @RAF1940: Long story, too long for a comment, but suffice to say that namespaces are created to create a division among names, and `using namespace` breaks that division by modifying lookup and potentially cause ambiguities and harder to read (interpret) code. The using directive does what it promises, but not everyone is aware of what that promise is. Lookup is complex enough without it :)

Comment: @RAF1940 - there are many questions on SO about compile-time errors that result from ambiguities because of `using namespace std;`. The primary purpose of namespaces is to make it easier avoid ambiguities; `using namespace std;` in effect says "damn the torpedoes, full speed ahead!"

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I find that the maintainability aspect of verbose namespacing is more valuable.  If I come across something like `boost::somelib::obscureclass::obscureiterator` I can at least follow the chain to find documentation, but if I just see `obscureclass::obscureiterator` I have to dig for it.

Comment: In my experience, `using namespace` should be restricted to only the most trivial academic exercises.  It has no place in a professional -quality codebase as it *effectively* combines the given namespace with the global namespace, which can lead to a massive number of naming conflicts and bugs that are very difficult to track down.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that using just `stringstream` implies that you have `using namespace std;` or `using std::stringstream`. Without one of those, the code without the fully qualified name will not compile.

The `using namespace std` is usually considered a bad practice, because it removes all benefits that you get from C++ namespaces - namely, name clashes. If you use the `using` directive, especially with STD, which has classes such as `list`, `iterator`, etc, you open yourself to the possibility for name clashes with your own classes.

This can in the best case result in weird compile time errors, or in the worst case, silent substitution of the functions that you call, with hard to trace problems.

Answer (score 0):

`std::stringstream` refers to one of many objects found in the standard library, `stringstream`.  If we think of libraries as physical library buildings, then your program has to go and "get the book" that is `stringstream` to use it.  This is what the `std::` syntax does, it indicates to your program that it has to go to the standard library to get whatever is on the right-side of `::`.  This works for many libraries, such as `boost::` or even sub-namespaces like `std::tr1::`.  (Note that technically namespaces are not equal to libraries, but we'll ignore that for this)

Now, by writing simple `stringstream` without the `std::` it implies that somewhere `using namespace std;` has been written.  Using our previous analogy, `using namespace std;` basically mashes all of those library books into your program.  You don't need to get them anymore, but your program is now cluttered with every book from it.  Naturally, this can cause problems if you do it with several libraries since now a book from `std::` might get mixed up with a book from `boost::`.